# Oracle package - Create a cursor using temp table

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, oracle12c

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with a stored procedure inside a package and need some guidance.

At some point inside the SP, a record, or set of records, are inserted into a temp table. I say possibly set of records because insertion happens inside a loop. When the loop exits a cursor is set using selection from this temp table and content of the temp table deleted.

Would this not mean that the cursor would now return empty dataset to the application calling it?

This is code; input is one or more Item IDs (I trimmed unnecessary code):

```
PROCEDURE USPGETOUTCOMEBYITEMCOI
(
IPSITEMIDS                VARCHAR2,
OPDQUERIEDON              OUT TIMESTAMP,
OPIERRORCODE              OUT NUMBER,
CUR_OUT                   OUT GETDATACURSOR
)
IS
LVIERRORCODE            NUMBER(38):=0;
LVSQUERY                VARCHAR2(4000):='';
V_NEWITEM VARCHAR2(38);
V_NEWITEM2 VARCHAR2(4000);
V_TEMPITEMID VARCHAR2(38);
V_NEWITEMSLIST VARCHAR2(4000) := REPLACE(IPSITEMIDS, '''', '');
V_ORIGINDATE     TIMESTAMP;

CURSOR cur IS
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_NEWITEMSLIST, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) V_NEWITEM2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY instr(V_NEWITEMSLIST, ',',1, LEVEL -1) > 0;

BEGIN
-- Loop thorugh each ITEM ID and determine outcome, add ITEM ID and OUTCOME to temp table
FOR rec IN cur LOOP   
    V_NEWITEM := rec.V_NEWITEM2;
    ....
    INSERT INTO TEMPOUTCOME
    (
      ITEMID,
      OUTCOME,
      ORIGINDATE
    )
    VALUES
    (
        V_TEMPITEMID,
        V_OUTCOME,
        V_ORIGINDATE
    );
    COMMIT;
    ....
END LOOP;
LVSQUERY:='SELECT ITEMID, OUTCOME, ORIGINDATE FROM TEMPOUTCOME WHERE ITEMID IN (' || IPSITEMIDS || ')';

OPEN CUR_OUT FOR LVSQUERY;

OPDQUERIEDON:= SYSTIMESTAMP;

-- Delete from temp table all item IDs used in this session
DELETE FROM TEMPOUTCOME WHERE ITEMID IN (select REGEXP_SUBSTR(IPSITEMIDS, '\''(.*?)\''(?:\,)?', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(IPSITEMIDS, '''(?: +)?(\,)(?: +)?''', 1) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE today_sales(order_id NUMBER)
ON COMMIT delete ROWS
```

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    cursor cur_temp is select
                           *
                       from
                           today_sales;

begin
    insert into today_sales values ( 1 );

    commit;
    for i in cur_temp loop
        dbms_output.put_line('There is data');
    end loop;
end;
```

So I executed above two codes and it doesn't print anything. This means as soon as you `commit`, data will be deleted and `cursor` will return 0 records.

And if you execute the same above code (plsql code) by **removing/commenting** `commit`, this will print data, which means cursor is returning records.

So answer to your question: yes, cursor will return empty data set as soon as you commit.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the same as what I included in my sample code. Is GLOBAL TEMPORARY same as a regular table? My temp table is called temp but it is a regular database table. I just don;t want to keep tons of data in it which becomes useless once cursor is returned.

Comment: `Global Temporary` and regular tables are different. You can use [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) to explore more. And if you don't want to get into much depth, you can just issue a `truncate` after performing your operations in procedure. This way it will be more understandable for others who are not aware of `temporary table` as it will use regular table and `truncate`